# Passing "&" by POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am passing variables to submit file via AJAX but I have problem when I'm passing variable that contains "&" character. I know why, because it's messing the string like id=1&name=blabla&something=q&a.

But how can I make it work?

Someone wanted code, here it is

```
$("#btnCatEditSubmit").click(function()
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "catEditSubmit.php",
                    data: "catID=<?= $catID ?>" + "&catName=<?= $catName ?>",
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

catName might be "Something & Something" and then I have problem.

Comment: Do you need to use PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to encode / escape them.

In PHP, you can do that with the [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) function:

```
$string = urlencode($string);
```

So in your code, do that:

```
data: "catID=<?= urlencode($catID) ?>" + "&catName=<?= urlencode($catName) ?>",
```

Or even better:

```
data: <?=json_encode(array('catID' => $catID, 'catName' => $catName))?>,
```

(jQuery allows you to pass a hash of key-value pairs directly, so jQuery can take care of escaping for you. Here [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) formats your array in a way understandable by javascript).

---

In javascript, you can do that with the encodeURIComponent() function:

```
var escaped_string = encodeURIComponent(str);
```

But as you are using jQuery, you can also pass variables directly with a hash.

Instead for doing this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: "a=b&c=d",
    ...
});
```

Do this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {a: "b", c: "d"},
    ...
});
```

And jQuery will escape everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the "&" character using %26

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to make your parameter values URL-safe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to url-encode your `&`. The code is `%26`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `&` character, as it has a special meaning in URLs.  You can do this with the native function [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or, since you are using jQuery, using the [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param) helper method:

```
var querystring = $.param({
    id: 1,
    name: 'blablah',
    something: 'q&a'
});
```